# Another CSS background image not showing, is my code wrong?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

Good day to you all,

I've been looking all over the place to figure this problem out. But I can't, and it makes me believe there is something else going on. Let's see.

I would wish to write a code for a banner on my Wordpress Bootstrap website.
[www.visionalmind.com](http://www.visionalmind.com)
This banner ought to be placed just below the navbar, and for this I've made a  within a full-width container. The class includes the image itself.

My desire is to make a banner like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image_background3

This is the CSS for header_banner:

```
.header_banner{
  max-width: 100%!important;
  margin: auto!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  max-height: 1080px!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-attachment: fixed!important;
  background-size:cover!important;
  background-image: url('https://www.visionalmind.com/wp-content/themes/visionaltheme/media/photo-1499951360447-b19be8fe80f5.png');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-darkblue">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="container pad_over">
      <a class="header_banner"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following.

- Tried to use the 'background' property in place of 'background-image'
  property.
- Tried using HTML instead by using  This worked, but I
  get stretching problems. I'm open for ideas.
- I've loaded the URL in my url bar to check if the image works, it does.

Comment: Your header banner has no height...

Comment: ... and zero width too.

Comment: you are try to give background to ancher tag <a> try to change it  , use <div >

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I've implemented it all, but still no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few small problems here. You were trying to attach the background the an "a" tag instead of a "div," and you also didn't assign a height to it.

```
#headerBanner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 1080px;
  background-image: url('https://www.visionalmind.com/wp-content/themes/visionaltheme/media/photo-1499951360447-b19be8fe80f5.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-darkblue">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="bannerContainer pad_over">
      <div id="headerBanner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check it working on **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4b087jch/)**

Comment: Hey, thanks for your awnser! I only had to change bannerContainer to col-12, because of how bootstrap works. But after that, it worked! thanks!